# IE and DOM Standard model

Tags: javascript, dom

Could anyone explain me the difference between IE and DOM Standard event model in simple terms?

Comment: The DOM is this standardized event model *in theory*, then there's IE, an ugly ancient evil demon that **just won't die**, or did you mean how the event listeners differ?

Comment: There's a good discussion on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events. Of course, it's wikipedia, so take it with a brick of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not DOM event 2 compliant: the dom event begins from the document element with "capture phase", and down to the target, then bubble upward to the document element. It is pretty difficult to implement that in IE.

Example:

```
<body> <div id="div1"><div id=div2></div></div></body>
```

If "click" event fires on div2, eventListeners run as:

- document (phase 1)
- body (phase 1)
- div1 (phase 1)
- div2 (phase 2)
- div1 (phase 3)
- body (phase 3)
- document (phase 3)

In your code you assume that all listeners are in bubble phase, but that is not a good idea because for example "focus" events have no bubble phase, and don't run correctly with your code.

Answer (score 0):

They mostly do the same thing*, but you just have to determine which one to use by which browser your client uses.  [Dustin Diaz](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/) created this namespace to easily determine which event model to use:

```
var Event = {
    add: function() {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            return function(el, type, fn) {
                DOM.$(el).addEventListener(type, fn, false);
            };
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
            return function(el, type, fn) {
                var f = function() {
                    fn.call(DOM.$(el), window.event);
                };
                DOM.$(el).attachEvent('on' + type, f);
            };
        }
    }()
};
```

* - I say "mostly" the same thing, because you'll notice that the DOM `addEventListenter` takes an extra parameter at the end, which indicates whether to use event *capturing* (`true`) or *bubbling* (false).  Events fire from the root element down the DOM tree or from the source element up the DOM tree, so this flag determines what the `event.stopPropagation` function does.  *Capturing* means that the element can call `event.stopPropagation` to stop event propagation to its child element.  *Bubbling* means that the browser can call `event.stopPropagation` to stop event propagation to its parent element.

Comment: Your `Event.remove` implementation won't work in IE. It is not trivial to get it working, and I suspect that's why Dustin left it out of his implementation in the first place.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: Yeah, I just copied and pasted the code.  I removed the problematic part and left the part that is helpful for explanation.

Comment: Your explanation for the third parameter for `addEventListener` is incorrect: you seem to be implying that it governs whether the event will propagate from its original target or not, whereas in fact it has no effect on *whether* the event propagates, just how it does so: setting it `true` means the event progresses from the document root down through the tree until it reaches the target; when `false` it does the opposite, i.e. starting from the event's target and progressing (bubbling) up the tree to the document root. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-capture